# Build and run Release Scheme in React Native using main.jsbundle

Tags: xcode, react-native

react-native: 0.41.2

The problem is that I'm trying to build and run using the Release Scheme with a main.jsbundle file I created using the cli. This is the command I used to generate that bundle:

```
node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js bundle --entry-file index.ios.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios
```

The bundle generates correctly, however, when I click the build and run button on XCode, every time the packager automatically starts up! Looking at the contents of the Application in the Products folder, I can assume that the bundle being used in the compiled application is the one being generated from the packager and not the one that I generated using the bundle cli command. Is there a way that I can somehow suppress this packager being ran when running the Release Scheme and use my generated bundle?

Answer (score 0):

Open the  App in xcode

in /AppDelegate.m

replace

`jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];`

with

`jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];`